# Weird behavior when creating, reading and deleting files in tests in Rust

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to write a test to a module, the module itself is not important.

The test part looks like this. In this two test I'm trying to do exactly the same thing: create a JSON file, read it and delete it (these are not real tests but these actions need to repeat from tests to test).

src/archive.rs

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::{fs, path};
    use crate::tests;

    #[test]
    fn test_archive_tar_archive_test1() {
        tests::create_custom_settings(
            r#"{
                "tmp_path": "/tmp1",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp1"
            }"#,
        );
        println!("reading {}", fs::read_to_string(tests::CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH).unwrap());
        tests::delete_custom_settings();
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_archive_tar_archive_test2() {
        tests::create_custom_settings(
            r#"{
                "tmp_path": "/tmp2",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp2"
            }"#,
        );

        println!("reading {}", fs::read_to_string(tests::CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH).unwrap());
        tests::delete_custom_settings();
    }
}
```

The second file as basic as the first one, these are common parts used in multiple modules:

src/tests.rs

```rust
use std::fs;

pub const CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH: &str = "/tmp/hvtools_custom_settings.json";

pub fn create_custom_settings(file_data: &str) {
    println!("writing {}", file_data);
    match fs::write(CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH, file_data) {
        Ok(_) => {},
        Err(e) => panic!(
            "Could not create custom settings file under '{}': {}",
            CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH, e
        ),
    };
}

pub fn delete_custom_settings() {
    match fs::remove_file(CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH) {
        Ok(_) => {},
        Err(e) => panic!(
            "Could not delete custom settings file under '{}': {}",
            CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH, e
        ),
    };
}
```

When running these tests gets me about the same each time with slight differences:

```
running 2 tests
writing {
                "tmp_path": "/tmp1",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp1"
            }
writing {
                "tmp_path": "/tmp2",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp2"
            }
reading {
                "tmp_path": "/tmp2",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp2"
            }
reading {
                "tmp_path": "/tmp2",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp2"
            }
thread 'archive::tests::test_archive_tar_archive_test2' panicked at 'Could not delete custom settings file under '/tmp/hvtools_custom_settings.json': No such file or directory (os error 2)', src/tests.rs:19:19
```

As we can see:

- reading the file in the first test returns the value which is written in the second test
- trying to delete JSON file in the second test fails (while reading works)

Sometimes both tests read contents written in the first test, sometimes the first reading attempt returns an empty string (results vary without code changes):

```
running 2 tests
writing {
                "tmp_path": "/tmp1",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp1"
            }
writing {
                "tmp_path": "/tmp2",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp2"
            }
reading 
reading {
                "tmp_path": "/tmp2",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp2"
            }
```

It's a physical filesystem (no NFS share or something). Also, as a side note, if I move contents of the second test to the first one like that:

```rust
fn test_archive_tar_archive_test1() {
    tests::create_custom_settings(
        r#"{
                "tmp_path": "/tmp1",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp1"
            }"#,
    );
    println!(
        "reading {}",
        fs::read_to_string(tests::CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH).unwrap()
    );
    tests::delete_custom_settings();

    tests::create_custom_settings(
        r#"{
                "tmp_path": "/tmp2",
                "archive_tmp_path": "/tmp2"
            }"#,
    );

    println!(
        "reading {}",
        fs::read_to_string(tests::CUSTOM_SETTINGS_PATH).unwrap()
    );
    tests::delete_custom_settings();
}
```

everything works as expected. Tried adding `thread::sleep`, doesn't seem to change the outcome.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tests run in parallel, so it is likely that two tests that access the same paths will interfere with each other. Use different paths in each test to prevent this.

Alternatively, you can force the tests the tests to run sequentially, in a single thread:

```
cargo test -- --test-threads=1
```

Comment: Thank you, @PeterHall, yes, this was the issue. Should have read this part of the documentation once again.